# How does a TTL gate input strain an ALS-TTL gate output, and how does it strain a CMOS gate output?

Tags: digital-logic

How does a TTL gate input strain an ALS-TTL gate output, and how does it strain a CMOS gate output?
Or do you maybe know where I can find resources on the topic?

Comment: Normally you would not be connecting outputs together, so outputs would not strain each others. If that is not what you meant to ask, please edit the question.

Comment: There are many different CMOS logic families with different drive strengths. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @CL. Thanks for looking into my question! We started learning digital electronics in school, so I am looking for a general idea of how it strains the output, or maybe whether there might be a book or web page about it, because I have not found any resources on the question yet

Comment: If you have a data sheet for your TTL chip, it will have input current values listed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The datasheet (here of the [SN74ALS04B](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74ALS04B)) tells you how much current an ALS input needs:

[image: ALS input currents]

The datasheet also tells you how much current an ALS output can supply:

[image: ALS output currents]

(The absolute maximum ratings might be higher, but these are the highest output currents for which an output voltage is guaranteed.)

CMOS outputs (here of the [SN74HC04](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74HC04)) are designed to be symmetrical:

[image: HCMOS output currents]

So both outputs have a drive strength that is much higher than needed for a single ALS input.

---

The output and input voltages also must match:

[image: ALS input voltages]

An ALS input must be pulled above 2 V when high, or below 0.8 V when low. The V<sub>OH</sub>/V<sub>OL</sub> values show that ALS and HC outputs can easily achieve that.